No artifact output from dotnet-ef migrations script in Devops Pipeline
I have a Devops pipeline which used to run under a windows-latest agent. We've recently moved it to ubuntu-latest for a variety of reasons. However since that change, the dotnet-ef tool has not been outputting the migrations SQL script to the artifacts folder.
This is the (simplified) YML for the pipeline:
trigger:
- dev

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET8 SDK'
  inputs:
    useGlobalJson: false
    packageType: sdk
    version: 8.x
    includePreviewVersions: false

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: "Build EF Migrations"
  inputs:
    script: |
      dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 8.0.7
      dotnet ef migrations script -p FooBar.Domain -s FooBar.API -o "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ef-migrations.sql" -i -v

# other build stages....

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: "Publish Artifacts"
  inputs:
    artifactName: 'drop'

The step in the pipeline works fine with no errors in the log. In fact, the output states it has created the file:


Writing '/home/vsts/work/1/s/ef-migrations.sql'...
Finishing: Build EF Migrations

The issue is that the Artifacts folder contains no reference to that file:

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Can you share your publish build/pipeline artifact task configured in your YAML?

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT sure, added

According to your PublishBuildArtifacts@1 task, the PathtoPublish is the default value $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory), which is /home/vsts/work/1/a. But your ef-migrations.sql is in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory), which is /home/vsts/work/1/s. You need to copy your ef-migrations.sql to $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) before publishing to artifact.

Thank for the response. I'm pretty sure it was set to that previously, but I changed it during debugging to the same folder as the CSV file output that you can see. Let me change it back and see what effect it has.

According to your PublishBuildArtifacts@1 task, the PathtoPublish is the default value $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory), which is /home/vsts/work/1/a.

According to your scripts -o "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ef-migrations.sql, your ef-migrations.sql is in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory), which is /home/vsts/work/1/s
Copy your ef-migrations.sql to $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) before publishing build artifact.
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: "Build EF Migrations"
  inputs:
    script: |
      dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 8.0.7
      dotnet ef migrations script -p FooBar.Domain -s FooBar.API -o "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ef-migrations.sql" -i -v
      cp ef-migrations.sql $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)


Glad to know your issue has been resolved. Happy coding!
